# Suppressing an onclick link event without stopping the actual page re-direct

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to disable the onclick function but still use the href to re-direct the user to the requested link. Example a header menu there are many links that looks like below :

```
<a href="//www.site.com/blah" onclick="DA_A('id',':per:shop:phones',this.href);  return false;" class="link" target="_self" title="">Phones</a>
```

I am unable to remove the "DA_A('id', ':per:shop', this.href); return false;" from the HTML page. However using a tag manager how would one go about injecting a snippet of JavaScript code function which will de-activate/mute the "DA_A" function but still make the link work as normal? Is it possible? It seems the function "DA_A" is a function that calls another ".push" function and pass some data.

What are my options? as I am unable to edit the menus in questions?

Comment: [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and maybe [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), depending on what else is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably remove the `onclick` from the element if you can run some javascript after the DOM renders:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("someId"); // or tagname, querySelector, etc
anchor.onclick = "";
```

You could also disable the function it calls altogether, depending on whether it is needed elsewhere:

```
window.DA_A = function() { /* do nothing */ };
```

The first snippet would need to be run after the DOM was rendered (for example, if you are using jquery then enclose it in a `$(function() {})`), and the second snippet would need to run after the `DA_A` function is defined in the first place.

Either of these by themselves should disable the onclick, but still allow the anchor to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet will do the trick:

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    document.querySelctor("a").removeAttribute("onclick");  // make selector more specific
};
```